# File explorer: cannot open a folder like a tree in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus

I have updated my computer to Ubuntu 13:04 and I have noticed that in Nautilus I cannot open a folder with the tree icon there was on the left in the previous version. With this option is easy to explore some folders remaining in the same folder with less effort.

I couldn't find any option in the preferences. Is there an option to recover this functionality?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure but see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286430/nautilus-3-6-doesnt-have-a-status-bar/286438#286438 regarding the SolusOS Patched Nautilus. It restores lots of old options. More info: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-solusos-patched-nautilus-in-ubuntu-1204.html

Answer (score 5):

As noted in [this blog post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/is-the-new-nautilus-a-step-in-the-direction-poll), that feature (along with many others like compact mode) have been removed in 13.04 and there are no options to re-enable them. You will have to find and install an alternate file browser - there are [several listed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28556/are-there-any-alternatives-to-nautilus) in this question.

Comment: How annoying!  What's the point of taking away useful features

Comment: From the available information, it appears to be a case of "we know what's best" in the part of the devs, and in this case they're just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about 13.04 but in my 14.04 you can edit preferences and enable "Navigate folders in a tree" from the display tab.

I learned it from here:
http://frayd.us/blog/enabling-file-tree-view-ubuntu/