# Nautilus progress bar not visible on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nautilus

I just updated my computer this morning to Ubuntu 14.04 and that's amazing, I really liked this update!

The problem is, when I was moving my files from the extern HD to my computer, the usual progress bar that nautilus shows didn't appear. So, I can't see how much data as already moved and the estimated time left.

How do I get the progress bar?

Comment: You can get the answer from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286430/nautilus-3-6-doesnt-have-a-status-bar

Comment: @MadukaJayalath I believe this question is asking about the progress dialog while copying files as opposed to the status bar at the bottom of the window. The progress dialog is also not mentioned in the list of changes in the question you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Revert to original Nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/experiments
nautilus -q
```

or uninstall nautilus and use [another file manager](http://www.junauza.com/2012/07/best-alternative-file-managers-for.html).