# Is there a way to add the status bar to Files (Nautilus) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nautilus, 14.04, files

I upgraded to **Ubuntu** **14.04** and the file manager changed; it's **Files** instead of **Nautilus**, and now there's no status bar where I can view the amount of disk space. I have a 120 GB SSD so I would very much like to see my disk space usage at all times. Is there any way to get the status bar back or are there alternative file managers which support the feature?

Comment: See this question, a bit old but still relevant. PCManFM is one option as an alternate file manager.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/286430/nautilus-3-6-doesnt-have-a-status-bar

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 recently - and I wanted to see the free space on the partition.
So after searching a while, I decided to code my own plugin that does just that, because I couldn't find anything that does that out of the box.

If it helps anyone, here is the link:

https://github.com/climaxx/Nautilus-Status-Bar-Replacement

It displays the free GB amount in a text bar below the address bar.

For files I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see the file size and I am used to that.