# Move icons on 19.04+ Gnome desktop

Tags: gnome, desktop-icons

By 19.04, [Gnome developers have finally removed](https://askubuntu.com/a/286438/449) Nautilus' ability to directly handle the desktop. [A shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/) was made to plug the gap, and this appears to be installed as a direct requirement of `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` and `ubuntu-desktop`.

I already appreciate that drag-and-drop is not possible to other applications [yet] but I have icons on my desktop that were positioned before the upgrade; icons that cannot now be repositioned.

[image]

It's driving me a little loopy. I have a few of these.

Given Gnome has users like me in its sights, I *am* trying to wean myself off the desktop but it's been an integral part of my day-to-day workflow since Windows 95. But regardless of your overarching desktop opinions, I'm not sure how I'm expected to deal with a desktop that *allows* positioned files but gives no mechanism to reposition them.

That seems insane to the point where it *must* be me doing something wrong.
My question is simple: **Is there a way to reposition icons on the Desktop Icons extension?**

**Edit:** Upgraded laptop and I can reposition icons. Any ideas why my desktop isn't complying?

Comment: In my case (just upgraded to 19.04) the icons are duplicated on my desktop. One version that I can move, one that I can't.

Comment: I would say it is a bug (and as such offtopic on this forum). Hopefully the Gnome developers come up with a patch soonish.

Comment: "I'm trying to wean myself off the desktop as an integral part of my day-to-day workflow" as somone who started out with windows 98, I've pretty quickly got rid of the desktop in my day to day life and I've stopped using it at all (when there is nothing at all on it my Feng-Shui is at it's max) and I can say I have no regrets. everything is so much faster this way. the desktop not being an icon on the taskbar nor part of alt-tab it just slows your workflow considerably if you ever have to use it at all. I would stongly recommend weaning to 100% desktop-free use, as I have.

Comment: To quickly wean away from the desktop, open Gnome Tweaks, go to the Extensions tab and disable the "Desktop Icons" extension. All your icons are gone. The corresponding files still exist in your ~/Desktop folder, where you can recover or delete them.

Comment: I just booted with Wayland and the icons behave as usual now.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> while moving icon, at final position release buttons and that's all

Comment: I'm on 19.04, this did not work for me

Comment: This is odd: On 20.04 with Shift you can move all the selected desktop icons except the one selected (right hover pointer)